# Does approximation usually exclude equality?

Tags: soft-question, notation, terminology, approximation

The Wikipedia article on [Approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximation) says that "An approximation is anything that is similar but not exactly equal to something else." Is excluding exact equality (i.e. $x = y \implies x \not\approx y$) standard when using the terminology "approximate"? For what it's worth, the ISO 80000-2 standard specifies that "Equality is not excluded" for the symbol U+2248 “≈”. I recently came across a use of the word "approximation" in a context that greatly confused me until I realized that they were implicitly excluding the case of equality, which was crucial for making their claim correct.

Comment: I do not think one is excluding equality artificially in the case of the irrationality measure. The definition requires an inequality to be satisfied by infinitely many rationals, and this fails when the number being considered is rational itself.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo No, the definition requires infinitely many integer pairs $(p, q)$, not infinitely many rationals. However, I don't think that this is the right page to be debating the issue on, as it has nothing to do with my question. Please comment on the other page.

Comment: This is not a matter of "debating". I thought you were actually interested in the mathematics.

Comment: I don't know why this question was closed; it seems fine to me.

Comment: The "terminology" tag is described as begin "on the usage and meaning of words in mathematics." Not sure how this question doesn't fit that criterion - I'm asking how a technical mathematical word is usually used by working mathematicians.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it matters all that much. I would use "approximation" in a situation where I could prove that something is close to another thing but I'm not bothering to check either way whether they are exactly equal. It may be that I end up approximating a function $f(x)$ by another function $g(x)$ which happens to be equal to $f$ for some values of $x$, but that wouldn't disqualify $g(x)$ from being an approximation. I would be very surprised if they were always equal, since generally I pick $g(x)$ deliberately to be much simpler than $f(x)$, so I would expect that to basically never happen anyway, e.g. for [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation).

As another example, I would use the phrase "Taylor approximation" to describe approximating a function near a point by truncating its Taylor series near that point even if the function is a polynomial, so that the approximation is exact at some point. I don't think this sort of usage is particularly uncommon either; google the phrase "approximation is exact" for more examples in this vein.

If you have a question about a particular case you should just ask about that.